# Place a negative sign in value

Tags: sql, select, negative-number

I have a SELECT query and would like to place a negative sign in percentage value if it's less than 100. Here is my query:

```
SELECT produces, amount, percentage FROM inventory
```

I tried:

```
SELECT produces, amount, CASE WHEN percentage<100 THEN '-'+percentage ELSE percentage END FROM inventory
```

But it did not work.

Comment: If percentage is a numerical field, you will need to CAST it to VARCHAR before you can perform text operations on it.

Comment: @tkvo....what was the error message?  What didn't work?

Comment: it keeps saying Syntax error before 'ELSE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the percentage-column is a numeric of some sort, not a string, you need to cast it to a varchar, something like this should work:

```
SELECT produces, amount, CASE WHEN percentage < 100 THEN '-' + CAST(percentage AS varchar(50)) ELSE CAST(percentage AS varchar(50)) END FROM inventory
```

Here's a working example:

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (produces int, amount int, percentage int)

INSERT INTO inventory values(1, 1, 110)
INSERT INTO inventory values(2, 2, 100)
INSERT INTO inventory values(3, 3, 90)
INSERT INTO inventory values(4, 4, 80)

SELECT
    produces, 
    amount, 
    CASE 
        WHEN percentage < 100 
        THEN '-' + CAST(percentage AS varchar(50)) 
        ELSE CAST(percentage AS varchar(50)) 
    END
FROM
    inventory
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to invert the sign simply multipy it with -1.

Comment: I only need values less than 100 to be placed negative sign, anything greater than 100 should be positive.

Comment: Than select all values less than 100 multiplay them by -1 and `UNION` them with the positiv rest

Comment: Good, simple and precise.